# Dynamic configuration of loopback REST connector

Tags: loopbackjs

I am struggling heavily trying to configure a model using REST connector. I've read the official docs: https://docs.strongloop.com/display/APIC/REST+connector
and I find it extremely confusing.

My scenario requirements:

- I'm connecting to several external REST services (always with the same baseURL)
- different loopback Models should access different external endpoints
- Basic authorization should be used, but the credentials differ from request to request

Some concrete questions:

1. should I have a datasource per model or only one (based on common baseURL)?
2. In case of only one datasource, how can I then **dynamically** set the concrete URL for each request?
3. How can I **dynamically** set the credentials for Basic authorization of a single request?

Comment: Those are very good questions, and could improve documentation a lot. Have you considered opening a ticket on the loopback github repo ?

Comment: I think the basic problem with loopback is the lack of clear and complete documentation. Examples are nice but to basic... The most of the rest should be somehow "guessed" by the developer...

Comment: Well, I don't have entirely the same feeling, but some things could be documented better indeed. Which is why we need to report documentation issues :) Let me know if you don't have time to open the ticket, I'll do it

Comment: Please be free to do it